# C++ Linked list - Deallocating node gives error

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, delete-operator

I created a linked list. Insertion and traversing works fine. Given below is the part in which I am deallocating the nodes. I have three pointers `now, nxt, start` all of which are of the datatype `node (the structure)`

```
now=start;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    nxt=now->link;
    delete now->link;
    now=nxt;
}
```

`start` stores the address of the first node, `now` stores the address of the current node under process, `nxt` stores the address of the next node which is accessed from the link part of the node at address `now`.

When I try to execute the program everything until deletion works properly and when it reaches deletion the program crashes and gives "Title : Stopped working" error. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: have you created now->link with "new" statement?

Comment: Are you sure the linked list has exactly `n` nodes?

Comment: Yes the linked list has n nodes

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's the problem:

```
delete now;
now=nxt;
```

You delete something and then perform an assignment to it.

Comment: Same happens when I delete `now->link`

Comment: The assignment is performed on the *pointer*, not the deleted object. `while (now) { nxt = now->next; delete now; now = nxt; }` is the correct (and idiomatic) way to iterate and delete a linked list. The new code in the question is buggy because it proceeds to use an object that was deleted.